# How to compose filters (with OR)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My messages are arrays of  message objetcs:

```
message = {'text':text, 'date':Date.now(), 'from':from, 'to':to}
```

I would like to apply a filter on ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="text in texts | filter" >{{text.text}} </div>
```

**that displays only those whose from="tom" OR to="tom2"**

Looks like the solution si to create a custom filter: Is there a simpler one **WITHOUT creating a custom filter** for that ?

Answer (score 0):

filter expression can be string, object or function, in your case you want a function so your filter expression could be

text in texts | filter:filterExpression

the filter expression function should be in the scope

```
$scope.filterExpression = function (x) {
        return x.from==='tom' || x.from==='tom2';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
phonecatApp.filter('filtertofrom', function() {
  return function(input) {

   if(x.from==='tom' || x.from==='tom2'){
    return "email Him"; 
    }
    else {
   return "No to from"    
}

  };
});

<div ng-repeat={{"text in texts | greet"}} </div>
```